file java unable to open in vs code
i'm new to java and i've try to study about open, read file on java through jGRASP. But I prefer to work with VS Code and when i code on VS, it can't open the file. On the other hand, it works on jGRASP.
Can anyone told me what did i'm wrong?
Here is my code:
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Pratice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dataFileLink = new File("CS121DataFile3.txt");
        Scanner fileScan = null;

        try {
            fileScan = new Scanner(dataFileLink);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("File not open correctly");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String fname, lname;
        int byear,dyear, age, tCount, yCount;

        tCount = 0;
        yCount = 0;

        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            fname = fileScan.next();
            lname = fileScan.next();
            byear = fileScan.nextInt();
            dyear = fileScan.nextInt();
            age = dyear - byear;

            System.out.printf("President: %s lived %d years", lname, age);
            System.out.println();
            
            tCount++;
            yCount += age;
        }
        System.out.println();
        double avg = 1.0 * yCount / tCount;
        System.out.printf("The avg age of the first %d president was %.1f", tCount, avg);
    }

}

When ever i use jGRASP, it work then print: President: Roosevelt lived 63 years
when ever i use VSCode, it doesn't work then print:"File not open correctly"

The program is probably being run from a different directory than the one where the file exists. Use File dataFileLink = new File("CS121DataFile3.txt").getAbsoluteFile(); and then System.out.println("File not open correctly:\n" + e);. This will show you where it's looking for the file.

complementing: new File("CS121DataFile3.txt") searches the file in the current working directory, since it is using a relative path. The current working directory depends on how/where the code is being started and depends on used IDE. Hint: never ignore the message of an exception; at very least include e.getMessage() in the error message (for development maybe better to also call e.printStackTrace()) and also better to include relevant data in the error message, as the absolute file path as given in previous comment (or dataFileLink.getAbsolutePath())

Simple solution, use an absolute path eg File dataFileLink = new File("C:/Users/myuser/CS121DataFile3.txt");

If you add the following to your code, it will print the path to the directory that Java is looking for the file that you are trying to open: System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
